# Getting Pixel Value of a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) data inside Cesium

Tags: javascript, arrays, cesiumjs

I'm trying to calculate Height Above Nearest Drainage (HAND) model of a DEM data. As far as I know, there should be some way to get the pixel values (elevation information) of the DEM and store it as an array (Similar to NumPy). That array can later be used to create a HAND raster. If my direction of thinking is correct, is there any way to fetch the pixel information in the Cesium?

I tried using geotiff.js to fetch the data but I don't think that would work.